# Restrict Application to Run on Allowed Computers

Tags: php, security, web-applications, mac-address, computer-name

Currently I am developing an application on PHP that I want to use on the specific computers that are allowed in my database, to restrict I may use MAC Address of the computer which is allowed to use the application.

I researched on various websites and articles about this issue, but I am not getting a proper answer.

No body tells how to fetch mac address of the visitor computer. Is there any alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> No body tells how to fetch mac address of the visitor computer.

You can't get the user's MAC address remotely. That information is only known to their LAN (specifically, their router's ARP table).

> Is there any alternative solution?

Yes: Recognize that you're [trying to solve an impossible problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem) that doesn't need solving in the first place.